# Format an array with a line break every n values using {fmt}

Tags: c++, c++17, fmt

Using the {fmt} library (the version from [github](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt)), is there a way to format a long array so that there is a line break inserted after every n values?

For example, say I have a vector of 22 doubles,

```cpp
std::vector<double> xs {
5.426221e-01, 1.129279e-01, 1.122641e-03, 9.013848e-01,
2.290470e-01, 7.200987e-01, 9.283220e-01, 5.108471e-01,
9.294625e-01, 8.451856e-01, 9.558900e-01, 4.757722e-01,
4.878883e-01, 8.988282e-01, 4.536756e-01, 3.459857e-01,
1.216555e-01, 3.884544e-01, 3.217016e-01, 4.758714e-01,
2.230451e-01, 7.985618e-01
};
```

`fmt::format("{:16.8e}", fmt::join(xs,""))` produces a single line of output. Is there a way to add a delimiter every 5 values, so I can get the following output?

```
  5.42622100e-01  1.12927900e-01  1.12264100e-03  9.01384800e-01  2.29047000e-01
  7.20098700e-01  9.28322000e-01  5.10847100e-01  9.29462500e-01  8.45185600e-01
  9.55890000e-01  4.75772200e-01  4.87888300e-01  8.98828200e-01  4.53675600e-01
  3.45985700e-01  1.21655500e-01  3.88454400e-01  3.21701600e-01  4.75871400e-01
  2.23045100e-01  7.98561800e-01
```

Comment: In C++23 you may use `std::views::trunk`.

Comment: @WeijunZhou ? Do you mean std::views::chunk ?

Comment: Yes. Brain fart.

Comment: I'm stuck with C++17 at work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### C++23

Use [std::views::chunk](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/chunk_view)

```cpp
auto const chunks = xs | std::views::chunk(5);

for (auto chunk : chunks) {
    fmt::print("{:16.8e}\n", fmt::join(chunk, ""));    
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sK8GfWbox)

### C++17

Specializing the `fmt::formatter` struct template according to the [official doc](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#formatting-user-defined-types).

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct fmt::formatter<std::vector<T>> : fmt::formatter<T>
{
    auto format(const std::vector<T>& container, format_context& context) const -> format_context::iterator
    {
        auto&& out = context.out();

        bool first = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < container.size(); ++i) {
            const auto& elem = container[i];
            if (i % 5 == 0 && i > 0) {
                format_to(out, "\n");
            }
            fmt::formatter<T>::format(elem, context);
        }

        return format_to(out, "");
    }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Txd1vbbYf)

Answer (score 2):

For posterity, here's what I ended up doing.

```cpp
template <typename T, size_t Ndelim>
struct periodic_join
{
    const T& container;
    const std::array< std::pair<int, std::string_view>, Ndelim > delimiters;

    template <typename... D>
    periodic_join(const T& container, D... delim)
        : container(container), delimiters { delim... }
    {
    }
};

template <typename T, typename... D>
periodic_join(T, D...) -> periodic_join<T, sizeof...(D)>;

template <typename T, size_t Ndelim>
struct fmt::formatter<periodic_join<T,Ndelim>>: fmt::formatter<typename T::value_type>
{
    format_context::iterator format(
        const periodic_join<T,Ndelim>& wrapper,
        format_context& context
    ) const
    {
        auto&& out = context.out();

        int i = 0;
        for (const auto& elem : wrapper.container)
        {
            if (i)
                for (const auto& delim : wrapper.delimiters)
                    if (i % delim.first == 0)
                        format_to(out, delim.second);

            fmt::formatter<typename T::value_type>::format(elem, context);
            ++i;
        }

        return format_to(out, "");
    }
};
```

Which can then be used as follows,

```cpp
fmt::format("{:16.8e}", periodic_join(xs, std::pair(5,"\n")))
```

It can also handle multiple delimiters with independent periods, which are inserted in the order of definition when the divisibility condition is met.

Maybe, with some polishing, this could be a library feature?